# unable to connect to tor control port on windows 7

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I am unable to use tor browser as it is not connecting to tor control port.
earlier version of tor was working perfectly but the problem started when i updated it.I tried disabled firewall and antivirus, also checked time but nothing worked. when i degrade tor again it works but i dont want to be unsecure. so there is any way to solve this

Comment: You probably need to fully uninstall the antivirus for this to work. Try booting into Safe Mode with Networking, to ensure there's no other weird so-called "security" software that's interfering with Tor Browser.

Comment: thank you cacahuatl for your help. It worked when i booted in safe mode.